# Toggle menu between two div container

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm probably having a fairly simple problem tho I cannot solve it myself.

I'm planning to have 3 divs, the left and right div should serve as kinda gateguards. The middle one should be hidden until I hover over one the gateguards. However I want the middle div to take up the remaining space left by the other divs. The transition should be smooth too, however that I can manage myself.

Heres my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .navi{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #middle{
        transition: width 1s ease-out;
        width: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0px;
    }
    nav{
        width: 100%;
        height: 169px;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav #left:hover + #middle{
        opacity: 1;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <div id="left" class="navi"><img src="Left.png"></div>
    <div id="middle" class="navi">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div id="right" class="navi"><img src="Right.png"></div> 
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this is, neither does it take up all the space thats left, nor is the transition looking nice, since the text appears at the first second of the transition and then just kinda starts fitting in, as soon as the space is available.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: When you hover left you want middle in the right side and when you hover right you want middle in the left side. And you want this change smooth. But what happens when you hover middle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that produces a pretty clean result is to trigger your animation via the parent element containing the sliding images. This makes achieving the effect you're after fairly simple:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ecxv34h/)

Hope this helps you out!

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav:hover > #navi-middle {
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

#navi-middle {
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
    <div id="left" class="navi"><a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a></div>
    <div id="navi-middle"><pre>Lorem Ipsum</pre></div>
    <div id="right" class="navi"><a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a></div> 
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, beautiful, thanks.
Also thanks to everyone else that answered so quickly.

Answer (score 3):

To do this with just CSS, the sidebars will need to come before the "middle" element so you can target them with adjacent selectors. You can use `order` to re-arrange them visually. Then you can transition/trigger a change on the `flex-grow`, `flex-basis`, or `width`. I'm transitioning `flex-grow` here via shorthand syntax.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

.side {
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}

#middle {
  transition: flex 1s ease-out, opacity 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#left {
  order: 1;
}

.side:hover ~ #middle, #middle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="left" class="navi side"><img src="Left.png"></div>
  <div id="right" class="navi side"><img src="Right.png"></div>
  <div id="middle" class="navi">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</nav>
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

.side {
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}

#middle {
  transition: flex 1s ease-out, opacity 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#left {
  order: 1;
}

.side:hover ~ #middle, #middle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="left" class="navi side"><img src="Left.png"></div>
  <div id="right" class="navi side"><img src="Right.png"></div>
  <div id="middle" class="navi">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: ...or to use controllers/mappers to one case or another. I also thought it's not possible at first, than realized I was just tackling it wrong. However, there's a huge difference between the question asked and the chosen answer, imo :).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu ah yeah, definitely confusing. The chosen answer is a neat effect but not what I was thinking either. When you describe elements as "gateguards," I suppose it's open to guessing and interpretation without an example or drawing or something.

Answer (score 2):

So, I think you can do something like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/gr6zzu8n/

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <div id="left" class="navi"><img src="http://ii.designtoscano.com/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi?FIF=/images/toscano/source/SH4210_2.tif&wid=2048&cvt=jpeg" width="200px"></div>
  <div id="middle" class="navi">
    <div>
      Lorem Ipsum  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="navi"><img src="http://ii.designtoscano.com/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi?FIF=/images/toscano/source/SH4210_2.tif&wid=2048&cvt=jpeg" width="200px"></div> 
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navi{
  display: inline-block;
}
#middle{
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 169px;
  position: relative;
}
nav #left:hover + #middle{
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're looking for something like this:

```css
body { margin: 0;}
left {background-color: #600}
right {background-color: #036}
container {
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
container * {
  flex: 1;
  transition: flex-grow .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
middle { 
  flex: 0;
  color: black;
}
container:hover middle {flex:1}
one,two {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
two { left: 50%;}
one:hover ~ right {flex: 0}
two:hover ~ left {flex: 0}
```

```html
<container>
  <one></one>
  <two></two>
  <left>left</left>
  <middle>middle</middle>
  <right>right</right>
</container>
```

The key is not to use the moving elements as controllers, but rather have two "controller" elements placed `absolute`ly over each half, dictating how the following ones (holding the content) should move and arrange.